# bootstrap datepicker not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker.js but after select the date the datepicker not hide.if i click in any other place it will hide?
what is the solution of this problem?
I have also tried this

```
$(".datepicker").on('changeDate', function(){
   $(".datepicker dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
});
```

but this is also not working and datepicker.js returns an error(that date is not defined).

Comment: Try this `$(".datepicker dropdown-menu").hide();`

Comment: `.hide()` is roughly equivalent to calling `.css( "display", "none" )`, except that the value of the display property is saved in jQuery's data cache so that display can later be restored to its initial value.

Comment: I have done it like.
    $(".datepicker").on('changeDate', function(){
 $("div.datepicker,div.dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
    });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.` to target class `dropdown-menu`:

```
$(".datepicker").on('changeDate', function(){
    $(".datepicker .dropdown-menu").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: thanx buddy but this is done like this.
    $("div.datepicker,div.dropdown-menu").css("display","none");

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question which datepicker you are using, but if it is [@eternicode's datepicker for boostrap](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), there is an [`autoclose`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#autoclose) option that does exactly what you want...